# Graph of adjoint operator

Tags: operator-theory

Let $T$ be an operator in $H$ with domain $D(T)$. Then the graph $G(T^∗)$ of $T^∗$ can be characterized by
$G(T^∗)={V(G(T))}^⊥$ , where $V$ is the unitary operator defined on $H × H$ by
$V {u, v} = {v, −u}$ .
Can any one prove this,please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 2007 and Math 1995 are the same person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any $u ∈ D(T)$ and $(v,w^∗) ∈ H×H$ we have the identity:

$⟨V(u,Tu),(v,w^∗)⟩H×H =⟨Tu,v⟩H−⟨u,w∗⟩H$ .
The right hand side vanishes for all $u ∈ D(T)$ iff $v ∈ D(T^∗)$ and $w^∗ = T^∗v$, that is if $(v, w^∗)$ belongs to $G(T^ ∗)$. The left hand side vanishes for all $u ∈ D(T )$ iff $(v, w^∗)$ belongs to $V (G(T ))^⊥$.
Standard Hilbertian analysis, using the continuity of $V$ and $V ^{−1}$ =$ −V$ , then shows that
${V(G(T))}^⊥ ={V(G(T))}^⊥ ={V(G(T))}^⊥$ .

---

End of proof: We have not analyzed till now under which condition the do-
main of the adjoint is dense in $H$.